# Failed to turn on/off IAP, Failed to update App Engine resource

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, identity, google-iap

When I want to use IAP with app engine, it failed with the issue:

```
Failed to turn on/off IAP
Failed to update App Engine resource.

Tracking number: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I restart IAP, still have this problem.

Comment: Did you activate the API?

Comment: yeah, I did, still has the problem

Comment: @Allen Are you getting this error while trying to enable the API via Console? Can you provide [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) steps steps? Try to follow this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/app-engine-quickstart) example and share with us in which point it's failing.

Comment: You can also try to enable it via gcloud command `gcloud services enable iap.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Additionally make sure you have the proper [permissions to turn Cloud IAP on and off](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/managing-access#turning_on_and_off) `appengine.applications.update`, `clientauthconfig.clients.create` and `clientauthconfig.clients.getWithSecret`. These permissions are granted by the Project Editor role.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, and I just deploy to app engine, and then I want to use IAP to control the access, once I turn on the Identity-Aware Proxy for app engine, the question arises. And I have the owner permission.

Comment: Hi Allen, in this case I recommend you to open a private issue so the support team can inspect your project. Please do it via this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, everyone, and I tried to add another Oauth Client Id, it works.